Identity doesn't create the tables in the database
I'm starting a new .NET 9 Blazor project. When I created the project, I chose to use the "Individual Account" option. So, the Visual Studio procedure added the Identity to the project. I don't change anything, the project is as it is out of the box.

When I run the project, I want to register a new user. When I click to register the user, I always get the error

Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'AspNetUsers'


This error occurs if I use a SQL database on Azure or a local database. I changed the connection string in the appsettings.json. In any case, the tables for Identity are not created.

You need to run dotnet ef database update to create tables.
If that doesn't do it by itself, run dotnet ef migrations add <Name> and then run dotnet ef database update.

Thank you for your answer,. I thought the tables were created automatically.
